# Derivative, slope or, the tangent of a graph with a shape which has corner like tips as in the letter V

Tags: derivatives, graph-theory, tangent-line, slope

Consider the graph of a function in the shape of  the letter **‘V’**, how would we be finding the **derivative, slope or, the tangent** of the function at the value of the function that corresponds to the **tip of ‘V’**?

Comment: The derivative isn't defined at the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of "tip" is called a *cusp*, and to see why the derivative is not defined at a cusp, look at the instantaneous slopes on either side of the cusp.

As you approach from either side, the slope will approach different values, and because the derivative is defined as a limit and limits only exist when they approach the same value from both sides, the derivative doesn't exist at the cusp.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative isn’t defined at the tip (or, in other words, the function is not differentiate at that point).

There are concepts like [semi-differentiable, left derivative, and right derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability), which can be applied to functions whose graphs have sharp corners.

Answer (score 0):

We can use sub-gradients as shown in the following figure, taken from [here](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf). This method particularly useful for backpropagation of neural nets in machine learning (e.g., RELU activation function, which is not differentiable everywhere).

[image]